# Re-signing an iOS .ipa for distribution (aka AppStore)

Tags: ios, code-signing, ipa

On our farm we create an iOS .ipa build. We sign this build with a developer certificate. This allows our devs to test the .ipa on their devices.

We now wish to re-sign and upload the .ipa to the AppStore. But this forces us to rebuild the .ipa with a distribution certificate. i.e. Instead of re-sign.

That seems highly inefficient. Is it possible to re-sign an existing .ipa as a distribution build? i.e. Rather than re-create the build.

Comment: Sorry COD3LICIOU5. It's not the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools you can use to re-sign the `.ipa` file. Check out [Fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane) set of tools - namely the [Sigh](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/sigh) tool's `resign` [lane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/resign.rb).